# How to correctly free memory in a dynamic array inside an struct

Tags: c, struct

I am struggling with the free of memory working with dynamic arrays. Considering the following code:

```
struct element{
   float a;
   float b;
};

struct list{
   int size;
   struct element *myelements;
};

int main(){
  
  struct list mylist;
  mylist.size = 0;
  mylist.myelements = (struct element*) malloc(sizeof(struct element)*4); //I reserve it as if i had struct element myelements[4]
  

  //i do stuff like
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i< 4 ; i++){
    mylist.myelements[i].a = i;
    mylist.myelements[i].b = i*2;
  }
  
  //I try to free myelements[2] for example, but i get an error
  free(mylist.mylements[3]);

  return 0;
}
```

My question is, how am i supposed to free the second possition of my array of elements. I have thought some alternatives involving realloc:

```
mylist.mybooks = realloc(mylist.mybooks, sizeof(mylist.mybooks) - sizeof(struct element));
```

but in that case wouldn´t I have to reorder the elements of the array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cant simply make a free only of your `free(mylist.myelements[3]);`, to make free you need to make it of all your array `free(mylist.myelements);`

Comment: `realloc` is good if you want a vector-like resizable array to ensure that capacity is always greater than size.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, how am i supposed to free the second possition of my array of elements.

`free` deallocates the entire allocation done by `malloc`, it cannot deallocate a part of one allocation.

A common way to manage a resizeable array is to maintain its capacity and size, and when removing elements move subsequent array elements to fill the removed element gap and reduce the size. The spare capacity is used for new elements when they get inserted. Calling `realloc` for every element insertion/removal is sub-optimal in terms of speed.